# Print using <link rel="alternate" media="print"> for external webpages

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Any possibility for using this?

```
<link rel="alternate" media="print" type="text/html" href="http://google.com" />
```

I have a wordpress site that I want to have alternate format when printing.
Using the code above will not work since google.com is not part of my website (Am I right?)
So I am looking for any thing that can help me with this problem.

Any workaround? Tricks?

Thanks in advance and more power.

Tricks using Javascript are also entertained.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that the alternate CSS that you want to use to control your sites printing lives on another domain?

Comment: Or are you saying you want to control how another site prints? Or are you saying you want to print a different site when someone tries to print your page?

Comment: he is saying, he wants to `link` to an `alternate` version of the page intended for `print` media. i think google.com is just a weird example  ?

Answer (score -3):

Your code tries to load the google.com as external CSS into your browser to use it to print your current page in a special style :-)

If you want to try to print google.com from your page, you have to load google into an iframe and say `iframeName.print();` with Javascript.

Comment: It is `rel="alternate"` not `rel="stylesheet"`. It doesn't try to load the page as CSS.